# How to query based on an previous object result? Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am extremely stuck with getting the right information from the DB. So, basically the problem is that I need to add where closure in my statement to validate that it only retrieves the real and needed information.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Post>> GetAllPosts(int userId, int pageNumber)
    {
        var followersIds = _dataContext.Followees.Where(f => f.CaUserId == userId).AsQueryable();

        pageNumber *= 15;

        var posts = await _dataContext.Posts
           .Include(p => p.CaUser)
           .Include(p => p.CaUser.Photos)
           .Include(c => c.Comments)
           .Where(u => u.CaUserId == followersIds.Id) <=== ERROR
           .Include(l => l.LikeDet).ToListAsync();

        return posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.Created).Take(pageNumber);
    }
```

As you can see the followersIds contains all the required Id which I need to validate in the post variable. However I have tried with a foreach but nothing seems to work here. Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: `followerIds` is a collection and won't have an `Id`. Are you needing to check against many or one?

Comment: Many, that's the problem. I know it's a collection but I don't know a way to check that.

Comment: Can you add the code with the looping that's also failing and specify the ERROR(s) you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that you can change that error line you have marked above to something like `.Where(u => followersIds.Contains(u.CaUserId)` which will return all entities with an CaUserID that is contained in the followersIds variable, however this still has the potential to return a much larger dataset than you will actually need and be quite a large query. (You also might need to check the sytax just a bit, shooting from memory without an IDE open) You are including a lot of linked entities in that query above, so maybe you'd be better off using a Select query vs a Where query, which would load only the properties that you need from each entity.

Take a look at [this article from Jon Smith](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/building-efficient-database-queries-using-entity-framework-core-and-automapper/), who wrote the book "Entity Framework Core In Action", where he talks about using Select queries and DTO's to only get out what you need. Chances are, you don't need every property of every entity you are asking for in the query you have above. (Maybe you do, what do I know :p) Using this might help you get something much more efficient for just the dataset you need. More lines of code in the query, but potentaily better performance on the back end and a lighter memory footprint.